# Kendo TreeList: check if node is currently shown

Tags: javascript, view, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, render

I have a scrollable Kendo Tree List. The rows of it can be selected. After selecting, the user can scroll away. But if he clicks on ,delete', a confirm dialog asks ,Do you want to delete the selected item'.

What I want is that after clicking delete, the selected row stays at the same position if the user can still see it. Otherwise, the row should be positioned in the middle of the list (scrolling node to middle).

Is there something like element.isCurrentlyShown ?

(Provisionally, I use

```
this.element.find(".k-grid-content").scrollTop($(selectedRow).position().top)
```

to ensure that the selectedRow is shown.)

Comment: Your approach is the right one, sadly kendo ui doesn't have that kind of feature yet :(